# Не запускается контейнер в Docker

Tags: docker

Запускаю `docker run -d -p 80:8080 --name furn --rm furn` . Но `docker ps -a` ничего не показывает. Если запустить без `--rm`, `docker run -d -p 80:8080 --name furn  furn` , то контейнер создается,а при попытке посмотреть `docker logs furn` пишет `sh: cross-env: Permission denied`

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:14 as client 
WORKDIR /app/client 
COPY client/package.json /app/client 
RUN npm install 
COPY client /app/client 
RUN npm run build 
FROM node:16-alpine 
WORKDIR /app 
COPY server/package.json /app 
RUN npm install 
COPY server /app 
COPY --from=client /app/client/build /app/client 
EXPOSE 8080 CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Команда `docker run --name furn --rm furn` создаёт контейнер из образа `furn`, присваивает ему имя `furn` и запускает. Раз `docker ps -a` ничего не показывает, значит созданный контейнер завершается раньше, чем вы выдаёте эту команду.

Ключ `--rm` указывает докеру, что созданный контейнер должен быть удалён после запуска. Вот почему вы не можете найти этот контейнер после завершения команды `docker run`.

Ваш контейнер, судя по всему, запускает внутри себя что-то на `node.js`. Проверьте `Dockerfile` и выставьте разрешение на доступ к `node_modules` и остальным компонентам, которые используются приложением.

Comment: Мой Dockerfile 
FROM node:14 as client

WORKDIR /app/client

COPY client/package.json /app/client

RUN npm install

COPY client /app/client

RUN npm run build

FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY server/package.json /app

RUN npm install

COPY server /app

COPY --from=client /app/client/build /app/client

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]

Comment: Для клиента вы копируете только `build`. `node_modules` для клиента остались в контейнере `client`? Если да, то вот вам и ответ - когда `webpack` пакует вашего клиента, он не находит нужные модули.

Comment: я в докере новичок), вы имеете в виду что в папке клиента должен быть .dockerignore, в котором прописаны 2 папки - node_modules и build? У меня вот такой файл есть, я там прописал node_modules и build. В папке сервер тоже есть этот файл, прописан только node_modules. Интересно, что локально на компе через докер собрал без проблем, в docker ps даже виден контейнер.

Comment: Решил строчкой COPY client/build /app/client/build, то есть сначала локально собираю проект и потом через докер все отрабатывает нормально. Почему докер сам только собрать проект не может..., в целом вопрос решен, благодарю)

Comment: @Сергей вы копируете в разные места. В комментарии про локальную сборку вы копируете в `/app/client/build`, а в Dockerfile вы копируете в `/app/client`. Поправьте на `COPY --from=client /app/client/build /app/client/build` и попробуйте запустить.

Answer (score 0):

В Dockerfile вместо строчек

```
COPY client /app/client 
RUN npm run build
```

Прописал строчку

```
COPY client/build /app/client/build
```

Проект заработал (в `.dockerignore` и `.gitignore` соответствующие настройки тоже сделать надо).